# Use devise to route to specific url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

When a user who is not signed in visits my homepage he gets redirected to `users/sign_in`which has a sign in form. When the user signs in he gets redirected to the root of the page. `http://localhost:3000/#/_=_`

But I want user to be redirected to this url `http://localhost:3000/#/home`

I've found [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) on the Devise page.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user_path
end
```

But I'm not sure how I should change this code to get devise to redirect my users to `http://localhost:3000/#/home` which corrosponds to a router-ui state.

```
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_home.html.haml',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    resolve: {
      postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
        return posts.getAll();
      }]
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Application Controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   "your_path_here"

end
```

for example if you want to go to root_path then "your_path_here" = root_path

Comment: How would this redirect my users to the `#home` part?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma you have to specify your path where you want to redirect after sign in.

Comment: Could you give an example? `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    root_path#home
  end` doesn't work because it comments the home out.

Comment: home is your action name? if yes then what is your controller's name?

Comment: I've created a home state action with router-ui and it reacts when the url is #home. So that's why I want to url to go to #home.